# Multiple models in Database from a Single DBT model

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am thinking to publish two models in the database from one model in DBT. One model is going to be with filter and the other one is going to be without filter. Have you ever created such a model like this with some jinjas? It would be so helpful if you can share with me some examples or resources please.
I would not create two models as they are the same models only the filter is applied as a difference. So the idea is to keep one sql file and publish two models with different names into the database.

I look forward to hear some suggestions from you.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you cannot do this with a single model, but there are lots of good alternatives. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254713/10813082) for a discussion about why you can't produce multiple assets from a single dbt model.

In this instance, since you're just applying a filter, I would just create two models, with one selecting from the other. This is a bread-and-butter use case of dbt's DAG.

`unfiltered.sql`

```sql
select
    -- your logic goes here
    ...
```

`filtered.sql`

```sql
select *
from {{ ref('unfiltered') }}
where
    -- your filter goes here
    ...
```

If that doesn't work, and the models share a lot of logic, but not all of it, I would wrap the common bits in a macro, and then invoke the macro in both `unfiltered.sql` and `filtered.sql` (as in the other answer I linked to).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for giving the idea.
I have also another solution actually and kindly would like to share it with you.

1. Create the table without filter
2. Post hook clone the created table
3. Delete from cloned table where the filter applied.

`post_hook` helps a lot to make it happen.
So basically the `post_hook` is going to be like this:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='table',
    post_hook= [ "create or replace table table_filtered clone {{this}}",
                 "delete from table_filtered where 1=1 and filter=true" ]
) }}
```

By cloning the table, we can keep the descriptions at both column and table level.