# Generating multiple views from one model

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

### The problem I'm having

I need to generate multiple views in BigQuery, each querying a different set of tables identified by a specific suffix. The challenge is further compounded by the need to manage these views across multiple environments (tenants, dev, sit, prod etc.).

### The context of why I'm trying to do this

The specific suffix used for table identification relates to a unique identifier in my business context, let's call it `ID1`. The number of such IDs is quite large and each needs its own view. Moreover, these views need to be managed across multiple environments (like development, staging, production, etc.).

### What I've already tried

I have considered several approaches to handle this situation:

1. **Separate SQL Models:** One approach would be to create a separate SQL model for each combination of `ID1` and environment. However, this would result in hundreds of files which could become unmanageable.
2. **Looped Run Operation:** Another option is to run a dbt `run-operation` in a loop, passing different arguments each time. However, I'm unsure if this aligns with dbt best practices.
3. **Custom Materialization:** I've also explored creating a custom materialization a little bit I'm not sure how it could help me here (I'm new to dbt).

I'm looking for advice on the best way to handle this situation. Is there a standard path in dbt for dealing with such complex scenarios that I might have overlooked?

**EDIT:**

I decided to go with custom materialization. This approach seems to be working for my use case at the moment. However, I'm new to dbt and I'm aware that this is often seen as a last resort. I'm uncertain of the potential consequences of creating a custom materialization, or what dbt features I might be missing out on.

```
{% materialization custom_view_materialization, adapter='bigquery' -%}
    {% set identifier = model.alias %}
    {% set my_ids = config.get('my_ids') %}
    ... other params
    {% set relations = [] %}
    {% for id in my_ids %}
        {% set table_pattern = table_prefix ~ '_%_' ~ id %}
        {% set query = generate_union_query(source_project, source_dataset, table_pattern) %}

        {% call statement('main') -%}
            create or replace view {{ target_project }}.{{ target_dataset }}.{{ table_prefix }}_{{ id }} as ({{query}})
        {% endcall %}

        {% do relations.append(api.Relation.create(
            database=target_project,
            schema=target_dataset,
            identifier=table_prefix ~ '_' ~ id,
            type='view'
        )) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ return({'relations': relations}) }}
{% endmaterialization %}
```

Comment: Option 1 is the most dbt like way to manage this. If the only difference between these views is the source table suffix then it shouldn't be difficult to create a script that generates the model files. Put the model SQL inside a macro that takes the suffix as a parameter then generate multiple model sql files that call this macro with a different suffix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run SQL model in dbt multiple times by looping through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250933/how-do-i-run-sql-model-in-dbt-multiple-times-by-looping-through-variables)

Comment: I’m a little bit concerned about managing hundreds of files across various environments and IDs. @tconbeer - in fact, your suggestion of custom materialization inspired me, and I've implemented it. It seems to work for my case, but, as you mentioned, this should be a last resort when no other options are available. I'm uncertain about the potential consequences of creating a custom materialization. For reference, I've updated my initial post to include the details of the custom materialization.

Comment: I'm curious what happens when you add tests (or other properties) to this model in a schema.yml file? I think you'll probably get an error that they don't belong to any relations?